finding bicyclic compound and identifying them, as well as larger aromatic systems
currently I am working on a code that is able to identify some chemical groups, rings and selectively if the rings are aromatic or not. However there seems to be a problem once I want to analyze annulated ring systems like sterone and larger aromatic systems like naphtalene or indole.
I know that the problem for the annulated rings comes from the part, that uses the length and multiplies it to not identify each carbon as one 'x_membered_ring'. And when using indole it finds an aromatic_6_memebred rings and a 9_membered one. How could I solve this issue so that the molecule can correctly identify all ring sytsem, while finding all unique ones and don't prints doubles? I have added some examples like Linagliptin (aromaticity, annulated rings) as well as Irinotecan  , Adamantane  , Cubane  and Alpha-Hopan . Does someone have any propositions or advice on how to fix this issue and being able to find all rings and even give information about the annulated rings?
Thanks a lot for the help and support!

#finding chemical functional groups

from rdkit import Chem

def find_smiles_patterns(smiles):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    if mol is None:
        return "Invalid SMILES string. Unable to parse molecule."

    # Define a list to store the chemical groups found in the SMILES
    chemical_groups = []

    # SMARTS patterns to recognize chemical groups
    smarts_patterns = {
    '[C]=[C]': 'Alkene',
    '[CX2]#[CX2]': 'Alkyne',
    '[CX3]=[CX2]=[CX3]': 'Allene',
    '[ClX1][CX4]': 'Alkylchloride',
    '[FX1][CX4]': 'Alkylfluoride',
    '[BrX1][CX4]': 'Alkylbromide',
    '[IX1][CX4]': 'Alkyliodide',
    '[OX2H][CX4H2;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Primary_alcohol',
    '[OX2H][CX4H;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Secondary_alcohol',
    '[OX2H][CX4D4;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Tertiary_alcohol',
    '[OX2]([CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])])[CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Dialkylether',
    '[SX2]([CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])])[CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Dialkylthioether',
    '[OX2](c)[CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])]': 'Alkylarylether',
    '[c][OX2][c]': 'Diarylether',
    '[SX2](c)[CX4;!$(C([OX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])]': 'Alkylarylthioether',
    '[c][SX2][c]': 'Diarylthioether',
    '[O+;!$([O]~[!#6]);!$([S]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Oxonium',
    '[NX3H2+0,NX4H3+;!$([N][!C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Primary_aliph_amine',
    '[NX3H1+0,NX4H2+;!$([N][!C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Secondary_aliph_amine',
    '[NX3H0+0,NX4H1+;!$([N][!C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Tertiary_aliph_amine',
    '[NX4H0+;!$([N][!C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Quaternary_aliph_ammonium',
    '[NX3H2+0,NX4H3+]c': 'Primary_arom_amine',
    '[NX3H1+0,NX4H2+;!$([N][!c]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Secondary_arom_amine',
    '[NX3H0+0,NX4H1+;!$([N][!c]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Tertiary_arom_amine',
    '[NX4H0+;!$([N][!c]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Quaternary_arom_ammonium',
    '[NX3H1+0,NX4H2+;$([N]([c])[C]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Secondary_mixed_amine',
    '[NX3H0+0,NX4H1+;$([N]([c])([C])[#6]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Tertiary_mixed_amine',
    '[NX4H0+;$([N]([c])([C])[#6][#6]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Quaternary_mixed_ammonium',
    '[N+;!$([N]~[!#6]);!$(N=*);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Ammonium',
    '[SX2H][CX4;!$(C([SX2H])~[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Alkylthiol',
    '[SX2]([CX4;!$(C([SX2])[O,S,#7,#15,F,Cl,Br,I])])[CX4;!$(C([SX2])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Dialkylthioether',
    '[SX2](c)[CX4;!$(C([SX2])[O,S,#7,#15])]': 'Alkylarylthioether',
    '[SX2D2][SX2D2]': 'Disulfide',
    '[OX2H][OX2]': 'Hydroperoxide',
    '[OX2D2][OX2D2]': 'Peroxo',
    '[LiX1][#6,#14]': 'Organolithium_compounds',
    '[MgX2][#6,#14]': 'Organomagnesium_compounds',
    '[!#1;!#5;!#6;!#7;!#8;!#9;!#14;!#15;!#16;!#17;!#33;!#34;!#35;!#52;!#53;!#85]~[#6;!-]': 'Organometallic_compounds',
    '[$([CX3H][#6]),$([CX3H2])]=[OX1]': 'Aldehyde',
    '[#6]([#6])(=O)[#6]': 'Ketone',
    'C=C=O': 'Ketene',
    '[$([CX3H][#6]),$([CX3H2])]=[SX1]': 'Thioaldehyde',
    '[#6][CX3](=[SX1])[#6]': 'Thioketone',
    'C=C=S': 'Thioketene',
    '[NX2;$([N][#6]),$([NH]);!$([N][CX3]=[#7,#8,#15,#16])]=[CX3;$([CH2]),$([CH][#6]),$([C]([#6])[#6])]': 'Imine',
    '[NX3+;!$([N][!#6]);!$([N][CX3]=[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Immonium',
    '[NX2](=[CX3;$([CH2]),$([CH][#6]),$([C]([#6])[#6])])[OX2H]': 'Oxime',
    '[NX2](=[CX3;$([CH2]),$([CH][#6]),$([C]([#6])[#6])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[#7,#8])]' : 'Oximether',
    '[OX2]([#6;!$(C=[O,S,N])])[CX4;!$(C(O)(O)[!#6])][OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,S,N])]': 'Acetal',
    '[OX2H][CX4;!$(C(O)(O)[!#6])][OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,S,N])]': 'Hemiacetal',
    '[NX3v3;!$(NC=[#7,#8,#15,#16])]([#6])[CX4;!$(C(N)(N)[!#6])][NX3v3;!$(NC=[#7,#8,#15,#16])][#6]': 'Aminal',
    '[NX3v3;!$(NC=[#7,#8,#15,#16])]([#6])[CX4;!$(C(N)(N)[!#6])][OX2H]': 'Hemiaminal',
    '[SX2]([#6;!$(C=[O,S,N])])[CX4;!$(C(S)(S)[!#6])][SX2][#6;!$(C=[O,S,N])]': 'Thioacetal',
    '[SX2]([#6;!$(C=[O,S,N])])[CX4;!$(C(S)(S)[!#6])][OX2H]': 'Thiohemiacetal',
    '[NX3v3,SX2,OX2;!$(*C=[#7,#8,#15,#16])][CX4;!$(C([N,S,O])([N,S,O])[!#6])][FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Halogen_acetal_like',
    '[NX3v3,SX2,OX2;!$(*C=[#7,#8,#15,#16])][CX4;!$(C([N,S,O])([N,S,O])[!#6])][FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1,NX3v3,SX2,OX2;!$(*C=[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Acetal_like',
    '[NX3v3,SX2,OX2;$(**=[#7,#8,#15,#16])][CX4;!$(C([N,S,O])([N,S,O])[!#6])][FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Halogenmethylen_ester_and_similar',
    '[NX3v3,SX2,OX2;$(**=[#7,#8,#15,#16])][CX4;!$(C([N,S,O])([N,S,O])[!#6])][NX3v3,SX2,OX2;!$(*C=[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'NOS_methylen_ester_and_similar',
    '[NX3v3,SX2,OX2;$(**=[#7,#8,#15,#16])][CX4;!$(C([N,S,O])([N,S,O])[!#6])][FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1,NX3v3,SX2,OX2;!$(*C=[#7,#8,#15,#16])]': 'Hetero_methylen_ester_and_similar',
    '[NX1]#[CX2][CX4;$([CH2]),$([CH]([CX2])[#6]),$(C([CX2])([#6])[#6])][OX2H]': 'Cyanhydrine',
    '[ClX1][CX3]=[CX3]': 'Chloroalkene',
    '[FX1][CX3]=[CX3]': 'Fluoroalkene',
    '[BrX1][CX3]=[CX3]': 'Bromoalkene',
    '[IX1][CX3]=[CX3]': 'Iodoalkene',
    '[OX2H][CX3;$([H1]),$(C[#6])]=[CX3]': 'Enol',
    '[OX2H][CX3;$([H1]),$(C[#6])]=[CX3;$([H1]),$(C[#6])][OX2H]': 'Endiol',
    '[OX2]([#6;!$(C=[N,O,S])])[CX3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])]=[CX3]': 'Enolether',
    '[OX2]([CX3]=[OX1])[#6X3;$([#6][#6]),$([H1])]=[#6X3;!$(C[OX2H])]': 'Enolester',
    '[NX3;$([NH2][CX3]),$([NH1]([CX3])[#6]),$([N]([CX3])([#6])[#6]);!$([N]*=[#7,#8,#15,#16])][CX3;$([CH]),$([C][#6])]=[CX3]': 'Enamine',
    '[SX2H][CX3;$([H1]),$(C[#6])]=[CX3]': 'Thioenol',
    '[SX2]([#6;!$(C=[N,O,S])])[CX3;$(C[#6]),$([CH])]=[CX3]': 'Thioenolether',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[ClX1]': 'Acylchloride',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[FX1]': 'Acylfluoride',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[BrX1]': 'Acylbromide',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[IX1]': 'Acyliodide',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Acylhalide',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Carboxylic_acid',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Carboxylic_ester',
    '[#6][#6X3R](=[OX1])[#8X2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Lactone',
    '[CX3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])[#8X2][CX3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])': 'Carboxylic_anhydride',
    '[CX3;!R;$([C][#6]),$([CH]);$([C](=[OX1])[$([SX2H]),$([SX1-])]),$([C](=[SX1])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])]': 'Carbothioic_acid',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[SX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Carbothioic_S_ester',
    '[#6][#6X3R](=[OX1])[#16X2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Carbothioic_S_lactone',
    '[CX3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[SX1])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Carbothioic_O_ester',
    '[#6][#6X3R](=[SX1])[#8X2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Carbothioic_O_lactone',
    '[CX3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[SX1])[FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Carbothioic_halide',
    '[CX3;!R;$([C][#6]),$([CH]);$([C](=[SX1])[SX2H])]': 'Carbodithioic_acid',
    '[CX3;!R;$([C][#6]),$([CH]);$([C](=[SX1])[SX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]': 'Carbodithioic_ester',
    '[#6][#6X3R](=[SX1])[#16X2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Carbodithiolactone',
    '[CX3](=[OX1])[NX3H1][CX3](=[OX1])[OX2H1]': 'Amide',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[NX3H2]': 'Primary_amide',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[#7X3H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Secondary_amide',
    '[CX3;$([R0][#6]),$([H1R0])](=[OX1])[#7X3H0]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Tertiary_amide',
    'c1cccnc1': 'Pyridine_Derivatives',
    'c1cnccn1': 'Pyrazine_derivatives',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=[OX1])[#7X3;$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([H0]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]': 'Lactam',
    '[#6X3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])[#7X3H0]([#6])[#6X3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])': 'Alkyl_imide',
    '[#6X3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])[#7X3H0]([!#6])[#6X3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])': 'N_hetero_imide',
    '[#6X3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])[#7X3H1][#6X3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])': 'Imide_acidic',
    '[$([CX3;!R][#6]),$([CX3H;!R])](=[SX1])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]': 'Thioamide',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=[SX1])[#7X3;$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([H0]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]': 'Thiolactam',
    '[#6X3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])[#8X2][#7X2]=,:[#6X3;$([H0]([#6])[#6]),$([H1][#6]),$([H2])]': 'Oximester',
    '[NX3;!$(NC=[O,S])][CX3R0;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]=[NX2;!$(NC=[O,S])]': 'Amidine',
    '[CX3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])[#7X3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])][$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Hydroxamic_acid',
    '[CX3;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[OX1])[#7X3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])][OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Hydroxamic_acid_ester',
    '[CX3R0;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[NX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Imidoacid',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=,:[#7X2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Imidoacid_cyclic',
    '[CX3R0;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[NX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Imidoester',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=,:[#7X2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Imidolactone',
    '[CX3R0;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[NX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[$([SX2H]),$([SX1-])]': 'Imidothioacid',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=,:[#7X2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Imidoacid_cyclic',
    '[CX3R0;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[NX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Imidoester',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=,:[#7X2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Imidolactone',
    '[CX3R0;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[NX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[$([SX2H]),$([SX1-])]': 'Imidothioacid',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=,:[#7X2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[$([SX2H]),$([SX1-])]': 'Imidothioacid_cyclic',
    '[CX3R0;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[NX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[SX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Imidothioester',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=,:[#7X2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[SX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Imidothiolactone',
    '[$([$([#6X3][#6]),$([#6X3H])](=[#7X2v3])[#7X3v3][#7X3v3]),$([$([#6X3][#6]),$([#6X3H])]([#7X3v3])=[#7X2v3][#7X3v3])]': 'Amidrazone',
    '[$([#7X3v3;!$(N([#6X3]=[#7X2])C=[O,S])][CX3R0;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]=[NX2v3;!$(N(=[#6X3][#7X3])C=[O,S])]),$([#7X3v3;!$(N([#6X3]=[#7X2])C=[O,S])][$([CX3R0;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]=[NX2v3;!$(N(=[#6X3][#7X3])C=[O,S])])])]': 'Amidine',
    '[#6][#6X3R;$([H0](=[NX2;!$(N(=[#6X3][#7X3])C=[O,S])])[#7X3;!$(N([#6X3]=[#7X2])C=[O,S])]),$([H0](-[NX3;!$(N([#6X3]=[#7X2])C=[O,S])])=,:[#7X2;!$(N(=[#6X3][#7X3])C=[O,S])])]': 'Imidolactam',
    '[CX3R0;$([H0][#6]),$([H1])](=[NX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Imidoylhalide',
    '[#6R][#6X3R](=,:[#7X2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Imidoylhalide_cyclic',
    '[NX3,NX4+;!$([N]~[!#6]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])][C][CX3](=[OX1])[OX2H,OX1-]': 'Alpha_aminoacid',
    '[OX2H][C][CX3](=[OX1])[OX2H,OX1-]': 'Alpha_hydroxyacid',
    '[NX3;$([N][CX3](=[OX1])[C][NX3,NX4+])][C][CX3](=[OX1])[NX3;$([N][C][CX3](=[OX1])[NX3,OX2,OX1-])]': 'Peptide_middle',
    '[NX3;$([N][CX3](=[OX1])[C][NX3,NX4+])][C][CX3](=[OX1])[OX2H,OX1-]': 'Peptide_C_term',
    '[NX3,NX4+;!$([N]~[!#6]);!$([N]*~[#7,#8,#15,#16])][C][CX3](=[OX1])[NX3;$([N][C][CX3](=[OX1])[NX3,OX2,OX1-])]': 'Peptide_N_term',
    '[#6][OX2][CX4;$(C[#6]),$([CH])]([OX2][#6])[OX2][#6]': 'Carboxylic_orthoester',
    '[CX3]=[CX2]=[OX1]': 'Ketene',
    '[#7X2,#8X3,#16X2;$(*[#6,#14])][#6X3]([#7X2,#8X3,#16X2;$(*[#6,#14])])=[#6X3]': 'Ketenacetal',
    '[NX1]#[CX2]': 'Nitrile',
    '[CX1-]#[NX2+]': 'Isonitrile',
    '[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])][#8X2][#6X3](=[OX1])[#8X2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Carbonic_acid_dieester',
    '[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])][OX2;!R][CX3](=[OX1])[OX2][FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Carbonic_acid_esterhalide',
    '[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])][OX2;!R][CX3](=[OX1])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Carbonic_acid_monoester',
    '[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])][#8X2][#6X3](=[SX1])[#8X2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Thiocarbonic_acid_dieester',
    '[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])][OX2;!R][CX3](=[SX1])[OX2][FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Thiocarbonic_acid_esterhalide',
    '[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])][OX2;!R][CX3](=[SX1])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Thiocarbonic_acid_monoester',
    '[#7X3;!$([#7][!#6])][#6X3](=[OX1])[#7X3;!$([#7][!#6])]': 'Urea',
    '[#7X3;!$([#7][!#6])][#6X3](=[SX1])[#7X3;!$([#7][!#6])]': 'Thiourea',
    '[#7X2;!$([#7][!#6])]=,:[#6X3]([#8X2&!$([#8][!#6]),OX1-])[#7X3;!$([#7][!#6])]': 'Isourea',
    '[#7X2;!$([#7][!#6])]=,:[#6X3]([#16X2&!$([#16][!#6]),SX1-])[#7X3;!$([#7][!#6])]': 'Isothiourea',
    '[N;v3X3,v4X4+][CX3](=[N;v3X2,v4X3+])[N;v3X3,v4X4+]': 'Guanidine_Derivative',
    '[NX3]C(=[OX1])[O;X2H,X1-]': 'Carbaminic_acid',
    '[#7X3][#6](=[OX1])[#8X2][#6]': 'Urethan',
    '[#7X3][#6](=[OX1])[#7X3][#6](=[OX1])[#7X3]': 'Biuret',
    '[#7X3][#7X3][#6X3]([#7X3;!$([#7][#7])])=[OX1]': 'Semicarbazide',
    '[#7X3][#7X3][#6X3]([#7X3][#7X3])=[OX1]': 'Carbazide',
    '[#7X2](=[#6])[#7X3][#6X3]([#7X3;!$([#7][#7])])=[OX1]': 'Semicarbazone',
    '[#7X2](=[#6])[#7X3][#6X3]([#7X3][#7X3])=[OX1]': 'Carbazone',
    '[#7X3][#7X3][#6X3]([#7X3;!$([#7][#7])])=[SX1]': 'Thiosemicarbazide',
    '[#7X3][#7X3][#6X3]([#7X3][#7X3])=[SX1]': 'Thiocarbazide',
    '[#7X2](=[#6])[#7X3][#6X3]([#7X3;!$([#7][#7])])=[SX1]': 'Thiosemicarbazone',
    '[#7X2](=[#6])[#7X3][#6X3]([#7X3][#7X3])=[SX1]': 'Thiocarbazone',
    '[NX2]=[CX2]=[OX1]': 'Isocyanate',
    '[OX2][CX2]#[NX1]': 'Cyanate',
    '[NX2]=[CX2]=[SX1]': 'Isothiocyanate',
    '[SX2][CX2]#[NX1]': 'Thiocyanate',
    '[NX2]=[CX2]=[NX2]': 'Carbodiimide',
    '[CX4H0]([O,S,#7])([O,S,#7])([O,S,#7])[O,S,#7,F,Cl,Br,I]': 'Orthocarbonic_derivatives',
    '[OX2H][c]': 'Phenol',
    '[OX2H][c][c][OX2H]': '1,2-Diphenol',
    '[Cl][c]': 'Arylchloride',
    '[F][c]': 'Arylfluoride',
    '[Br][c]': 'Arylbromide',
    '[I][c]': 'Aryliodide',
    '[SX2H][c]': 'Arylthiol',
    '[c]=[NX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6;!$([C]=[N,S,O])])]': 'Iminoarene',
    '[c]=[OX1]': 'Oxoarene',
    '[c]=[SX1]': 'Thioarene',
    '[nX3H1+0]': 'Hetero_N_basic_H',
    '[nX3H0+0]': 'Hetero_N_basic_no_H',
    '[nX2,nX3+]': 'Hetero_N_nonbasic',
    '[o]': 'Hetero_O',
    '[sX2]': 'Hetero_S',
    '[a;!c]': 'Heteroaromatic',
    '[!#6;!R0]': 'Heterocylcic',
    '[NX2](=[OX1])[O;$([X2]),$([X1-])]': 'Nitrite',
    '[SX2][NX2]=[OX1]': 'Thionitrite',
    '[$([NX3](=[OX1])(=[OX1])[O;$([X2]),$([X1-])]),$([NX3+]([OX1-])(=[OX1])[O;$([X2]),$([X1-])])]': 'Nitrate',
    '[$([NX3](=O)=O),$([NX3+](=O)[O-])][!#8]': 'Nitro',
    '[NX2](=[OX1])[!#7;!#8]': 'Nitroso',
    '[NX1]~[NX2]~[NX2,NX1]': 'Azide',
    '[CX3](=[OX1])[NX2]~[NX2]~[NX1]': 'Acylazide',
    '[$([#6]=[NX2+]=[NX1-]),$([#6-]-[NX2+]#[NX1])]': 'Diazo',
    '[#6][NX2+]#[NX1]': 'Diazonium',
    '[#7;!$(N*=O)][NX2]=[OX1]': 'Nitrosamine',
    '[NX2](=[OX1])N-*=O': 'Nitrosamide',
    '[$([#7+][OX1-]),$([#7v5]=[OX1]);!$([#7](~[O])~[O]);!$([#7]=[#7])]': 'N-Oxide',
    '[NX3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6]);!$(NC=[O,N,S])][NX3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6]);!$(NC=[O,N,S])]': 'Hydrazine',
    '[NX3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6]);!$(NC=[O,N,S])][NX2]=[#6]': 'Hydrazone',
    '[NX3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6]);!$(NC=[O,N,S])][OX2;$([H1]),$(O[#6;!$(C=[N,O,S])])]': 'Hydroxylamine',
    '[SX2][NX2]=[OX1]': 'Thionitrite',
    '[SX4](=[OX1])(=[OX1])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Sulfuric_acid',
    '[SX4](=[OX1])(=[OX1])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Sulfuric_monoester',
    '[SX4](=[OX1])(=[OX1])([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Sulfuric_diester',
    '[SX4](=[OX1])(=[OX1])([#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Sulfuric_monoamide',
    '[SX4](=[OX1])(=[OX1])([#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]': 'Sulfuric_diamide',
    '[SX4](=[OX1])(=[OX1])([#7X3][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Sulfuric_esteramide',
    '[SX4D4](=[!#6])(=[!#6])([!#6])[!#6]': 'Sulfuric_derivative',
    '[SX4;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[OX1])(=[OX1])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Sulfonic_acid',
    '[SX4;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[OX1])(=[OX1])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]': 'Sulfonamide',
    '[SX4;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[OX1])(=[OX1])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Sulfonic_ester',
    '[SX4;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[OX1])(=[OX1])[FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Sulfonic_halide',
    '[SX4;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[!#6])(=[!#6])[!#6]': 'Sulfonic_derivative',
    '[SX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[OX1])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Sulfinic_acid',
    '[SX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[OX1])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]': 'Sulfinic_amide',
    '[SX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[OX1])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Sulfinic_ester',
    '[SX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[OX1])[FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Sulfinic_halide',
    '[SX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])](=[!#6])[!#6]': 'Sulfinic_derivative',
    '[SX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])][$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Sulfenic_acid',
    '[SX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])][#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]': 'Sulfenic_amide',
    '[SX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])][OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]': 'Sulfenic_ester',
    '[SX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])][FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1]': 'Sulfenic_halide',
    '[SX2;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])][!#6]': 'Sulfenic_derivative',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Phosphoric_acid',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]' : 'Phosphoric_monoester',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]' : 'Phosphoric_diester',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]' : 'Phosphoric_triester',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphoric_monoamide',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])([#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphoric_diamide',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])([#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphoric_triamide',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphoric_monoestermonoamide',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphoric_diestermonoamide',
    '[PX4D4](=[OX1])([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])([#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphoric_monoesterdiamide',
    '[PX4D4](=[!#6])([!#6])([!#6])[!#6]' : 'Phosphoric_acid_derivative',
    '[PX4;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6])](=[OX1])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]': 'Phosphinic_acid',
    '[PX4;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6])](=[OX1])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]' : 'Phosphinic_ester',
    '[PX4;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6])](=[OX1])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphinic_amide',
    '[PX4;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6])](=[!#6])[!#6]' : 'Phosphinic_acid_derivative',
    '[PX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])[$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]' : 'Phosphonous_acid',
    '[PX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]' : 'Phosphonous_monoester',
    '[PX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]' : 'Phosphonous_diester',
    '[PX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]([$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphonous_monoamide',
    '[PX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]([#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphonous_diamide',
    '[PX3;$([H1]),$([H0][#6])]([OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphonous_esteramide',
    '[PX3;$([D2]),$([D3][#6])]([!#6])[!#6]' : 'Phosphonous_derivatives',
    '[PX3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6])][$([OX2H]),$([OX1-])]' : 'Phosphinous_acid',
    '[PX3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6])][OX2][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]' : 'Phosphinous_ester',
    '[PX3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6])][#7X3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])]),$([#7]([#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])[#6;!$(C=[O,N,S])])]' : 'Phosphinous_amide',
    '[PX3;$([H2]),$([H1][#6]),$([H0]([#6])[#6])][!#6]' : 'Phosphinous_derivatives',
    '[SiX4]([#6])([#6])([#6])[#6]': 'Quart_silane',
    '[SiX4;$([H1]([#6])([#6])[#6]),$([H2]([#6])[#6]),$([H3][#6]),$([H4])]': 'Non-quart_silane',
    '[SiX4]([FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])([#6])([#6])[#6]': 'Silylmonohalide',
    '[SiX4]([!#6])([#6])([#6])[#6]': 'Het_trialkylsilane',
    '[SiX4]([!#6])([!#6])([#6])[#6]': 'Dihet_dialkylsilane',
    '[SiX4]([!#6])([!#6])([!#6])[#6]': 'Trihet_alkylsilane',
    '[SiX4]([!#6])([!#6])([!#6])[!#6]': 'Silicic_acid_derivative',
    '[BX3]([#6])([#6])[#6]': 'Trialkylborane',
    '[BX3]([!#6])([!#6])[!#6]': 'Boric_acid_derivatives',
    '[BX3]([!#6])([!#6])[!#6]': 'Boronic_acid_derivative',
    '[BH1,BH2,BH3,BH4]': 'Borohydride',
    '[BX4]': 'Quaternary_boron',
    '[!#6;!R0]': 'Heterocyclic',
    '[OX2r3]1[#6r3][#6r3]1': 'Epoxide',
    '[NX3H1r3]1[#6r3][#6r3]1': 'NH_aziridine',
    '[D4R;$(*(@*)(@*)(@*)@*)]': 'Spiro',
    '[R;$(*(@*)(@*)@*);!$([R2;$(*(@*)(@*)(@*)@*)])]@[R;$(*(@*)(@*)@*);!$([R2;$(*(@*)(@*)(@*)@*)])]' : 'Annulated_rings',
    '[R;$(*(@*)(@*)@*);!$([D4R;$(*(@*)(@*)(@*)@*)]);!$([R;$(*(@*)(@*)@*);!$([R2;$(*(@*)(@*)(@*)@*)])]@[R;$(*(@*)(@*)@*);!$([R2;$(*(@*)(@*)(@*)@*)])])]' : 'Bridged_rings',
    '[OX2;$([r5]1@C@C@C(O)@C1),$([r6]1@C@C@C(O)@C(O)@C1)]': 'Sugar_pattern_1',
    '[OX2;$([r5]1@C(!@[OX2,NX3,SX2,FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])@C@C@C1),$([r6]1@C(!@[OX2,NX3,SX2,FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])@C@C@C@C1)]': 'Sugar_pattern_2',
    '[OX2;$([r5]1@C(!@[OX2,NX3,SX2,FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])@C@C(O)@C1),$([r6]1@C(!@[OX2,NX3,SX2,FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])@C@C(O)@C(O)@C1)]': 'Sugar_pattern_combi',
    '[OX2;$([r5]1@C(!@[OX2H1])@C@C@C1),$([r6]1@C(!@[OX2H1])@C@C@C@C1)]': 'Sugar_pattern_2_reducing',
    '[OX2;$([r5]1@[C@@](!@[OX2,NX3,SX2,FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])@C@C@C1),$([r6]1@[C@@](!@[OX2,NX3,SX2,FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])@C@C@C@C1)]': 'Sugar_pattern_2_alpha',
    '[OX2;$([r5]1@[C@](!@[OX2,NX3,SX2,FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])@C@C@C1),$([r6]1@[C@](!@[OX2,NX3,SX2,FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1])@C@C@C@C1)]': 'Sugar_pattern_2_beta',
    '*#*[*]=,#,:[*]': 'Conjugated_tripple_bond',
    '[$(*=O),$([#16,#14,#5]),$([#7]([#6]=[OX1]))][#8X2][$(*=O),$([#16,#14,#5]),$([#7]([#6]=[OX1]))]': 'Mixed_anhydrides',
    '[FX1,ClX1,BrX1,IX1][!#6]': 'Halogen_on_hetero',
    '[F,Cl,Br,I;!$([X1]);!$([X0-])]': 'Halogen_multi_subst',
    '[F][c1ccccc1]': 'Fluoride_benzyl',
    '[Cl][c1ccccc1]': 'Chloride_benzyl',
    '[Br][c1ccccc1]': 'Bromide_benzyl',
    '[I][c1ccccc1]': 'Iodine_benzyl',
    'C1C2CC3CC1CC(C2)C3': 'Adamantane_Derivative',
    'C1CCC2C(C1)CCC3C2CCC4C3CCC4': 'Sterone_Derivative',
    }

    # Dictionary to store matches for each chemical group
    matches_dict = {name: [] for name in smarts_patterns.values()}

    # Iterate over each SMARTS pattern and find matches in the molecule
    for pattern, name in smarts_patterns.items():
        matches = mol.GetSubstructMatches(Chem.MolFromSmarts(pattern))
        if matches:
            matches_dict[name].extend(matches)

    # Keep track of unique matches for each chemical group
    unique_matches = set()
    for matches in matches_dict.values():
        for match in matches:
            unique_matches.add(tuple(match))

    # Convert unique matches back to a list of chemical groups
    for name, matches in matches_dict.items():
        for match in matches:
            if tuple(match) in unique_matches:
                chemical_groups.append(name)
                unique_matches.remove(tuple(match))

    # Return the list of identified chemical groups
    return chemical_groups

#finding non aromatic rings, doesn't work for annulated rings
from rdkit import Chem

def find_unique_non_aromatic_rings(smiles):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    if mol is None:
        return "Invalid SMILES string. Unable to parse molecule."

    # Define SMARTS patterns to recognize rings of specific sizes
    ring_smarts = {
        '3_membered_ring': '[r3]',
        '4_membered_ring': '[r4]',
        '5_membered_ring': '[r5]',
        '6_membered_ring': '[r6]',
        '7_membered_ring': '[r7]',
        '8_membered_ring': '[r8]',
        '9_membered_ring': '[r9]',
        '10_membered_ring': '[r10]',
    }

    # Define a list to store the chemical groups found in the SMILES
    chemical_groups = []

    # Find matches of each ring pattern in the molecule
    for name, pattern in ring_smarts.items():
        ring_size = int(name.split('_')[0])  # Extract the ring size from the name
        ring_matches = mol.GetSubstructMatches(Chem.MolFromSmarts(pattern))
        non_aromatic_rings = [match for match in ring_matches if not any(mol.GetAtomWithIdx(idx).GetIsAromatic() for idx in match)] #exclude all aromatic rings
        unique_rings_count = len(non_aromatic_rings) // ring_size  # Correctly count unique rings
        if unique_rings_count > 0:
            chemical_groups.extend([name] * unique_rings_count)

    # Return the list of identified chemical groups
    return chemical_groups

#finding aromatic rings
from rdkit import Chem

def find_aromatic_ring(smiles):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    if mol is None:
        return "Invalid SMILES string. Unable to parse molecule."

    # Define SMARTS patterns to recognize aromatic rings of specific sizes
    aromatic_ring_smarts = {
        '3_membered_aromatic_ring': '[a]1[a][a]1',
        '4_membered_aromatic_ring': '[a]1[a][a][a]1',
        '5_membered_aromatic_ring': '[a]1[a][a][a][a]1',
        '6_membered_aromatic_ring': '[a]1[a][a][a][a][a]1',
        '7_membered_aromatic_ring': '[a]1[a][a][a][a][a][a]1',
        '8_membered_aromatic_ring': '[a]1[a][a][a][a][a][a][a]1',
        '9_membered_aromatic_ring': '[a]1[a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a]1',
        '10_membered_aromatic_ring': '[a]1[a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a]1',
        'naphthalene': '[a]1[a][a][a]2[a][a][a][a][a]2[a]1',
        #other larger systems...
    }

    # Define a list to store the chemical groups found in the SMILES
    chemical_groups = []

    # Find matches of each aromatic ring pattern in the molecule
    for name, pattern in aromatic_ring_smarts.items():
        pattern_mol = Chem.MolFromSmarts(pattern)
        if pattern_mol:
            matches = mol.GetSubstructMatches(pattern_mol)
            for match in matches:
                ring_size = len(match)
                if all(mol.GetAtomWithIdx(idx).GetIsAromatic() for idx in match):
                    chemical_groups.append(f'{ring_size}_membered_aromatic_ring')

    return chemical_groups

#Example Usage 2
Sterone  = "C1CCC2C(C1)CCC3C2CCC4C3CCC4" 
Indole ="C1=CC=C2C(=C1)C=CN2"
Napthalene ="C1=CC=C2C=CC=CC2=C1"
Linagliptin = "CC#CC[N]1C3=C(N=C1N2CCCC(C2)N)N(C(=O)N(C3=O)CC5=NC4=CC=CC=C4C(=N5)C)C" 
Irinotecan = "CCC1=C2CN3C(=CC4=C(C3=O)COC(=O)[C@@]4(CC)O)C2=NC5=C1C=C(C=C5)OC(=O)N6CCC(CC6)N7CCCCC7" 
Adamantane = "C1C2CC3CC1CC(C2)C3" 
Cubane = "C12C3C4C1C5C2C3C45" 
Alpha_Hopan = "CC(C)[C@H]1CC[C@]2([C@@H]1CC[C@@]3([C@@H]2CC[C@H]4[C@]3(CC[C@@H]5[C@@]4(CCCC5(C)C)C)C)C)C"


molecules = [ Sterone, Indole, Napthalene, Linagliptin, Irinotecan, Adamantane, Cubane,  Alpha_Hopan ]
for i in molecules:
        
    smiles_string = i
        
    print(smiles_string)
        
    chemical_groups_found = find_smiles_patterns(smiles_string)
    unique_ring_matches = find_unique_non_aromatic_rings(smiles_string)
    aromatic_ring_matches = find_aromatic_ring(smiles_string)
    print("Chemical groups found:", chemical_groups_found)
    print("Non-aromatic rings found:", unique_ring_matches)
    print("Aromatic rings found:", aromatic_ring_matches)



see https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/message/23801106/  ; https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.rdchem.html#rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol.GetRingInfo : Returns the number of molecule’s RingInfo object. ; You can interrogate the RingInfo object to tell you the atoms that make up each ring:  ri.AtomRings() . To detect aromatic rings, I (: Greg L.) )would loop over the bonds in each ring and
flag the ring as aromatic if all bonds are aromatic:


note that in the case where the aromaticity is due to fused rings
instead of individual ones (there's an example in the pdf above), this
approach will fail because GetRingInfo() only returns the smallest
rings. This is not a situation that occurs very frequently, but if you
need to work around it, you'll have to do the graph-traversal
yourself.


Hi there, thanks again for your help. It doesn't print anything. I don't know if this is an error from my side. Could you tell me which of the molecules I sent could now correctly be identified? And how would I need to proceed to find the fused aromatic rings?

https://ctr.fandom.com/wiki/Ring_counts_in_a_SMILES_file

https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/discussions/6762 How to check if a SMILES has a fused ring

Nice, that is very cool. Do you have an idea how I can fuse these codes in order to write something that can identify just all rings, and mention that they are fused, it is not necessary to specify where or how they are fused, only that it finds all rings and if they are fused or not

For example the fusing bonds here are not considered to be aromatic by the RDKit:

'[!#6;!R0]': 'Heterocylcic' is present twice in your dictionary smarts_patterns

@pippo1980 thanks a lot for your help! It really helped me solve the issue. You can check out the final code on https://github.com/thesonofmoon/ProgProject under the file Final_Code_Cédric_Baerlocher_Aguilar.ipynb if you are curious. In any case I resolve the issues and apart from some minor errors on the smarts I think it works great! I truly appreciated the help!

what does #finding non aromatic rings, doesn't work for annulated rings means ? _I mean annulated ? the way they are created/syntheyized ? or means fused rings ?

I am not sure if I understand the question, maybe you looked at an old code. I have pushed a new one, otherwise I can create a new post if you like so you can check it out.

I was just wondering about the meaning of "annulated ring" in your code ?

Cant you use Find the maximum common substructure of a set of molecules rdkit.Chem.MCS module https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.MCS.html#module-rdkit.Chem.MCS and scan your molecules against a set of predefined rings of interest and keep them if the maximun common substruvmcted returned is equal to the predefined ring used for comparison ?

I am not sure how this will output a list of values as predefined in my list of smarts. I understand that this would be better so that my code only finds anthracene and not twice naphtalene and anthracene. However I am not sure how I would need to implement this.

if you find an answer by yourself , you can answer your own question and accept it, still wondering about what annulated ring means in your code

have a look at what I've found in documentation https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#count-ring-systems --> Count Ring Systems

Ahh I see, well annulated rings means that the rings are fused together, but I deleted the smarts. However other than that I think the code works well, only it cannot recognize the systems like napthalene and larger aromatic system as its own. The only thing that it cannot do is differentiating between cis and trans double bonds… But I will figure it out :)

Ok I had the idea that fused rings are made actualy fusing 2 rings while annulated rings while annulated rings are made fusing non ring components or closing a non rimg component ... so thats why I wasnt able to understand it in your code but maybe my chemistry past is fading away and I am wrong

No you are absolutely correct, but as my code will be used further for reactions that is why I already wanted to use this term :)
